# layout_weight does not work when the layout inside the relative layout

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

layout_weight does not work when the Linearlayout inside the relative layout, only the problem is in layout_weight, that is showing properly in design view but while compile its getting error and stop compile
my code is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/ll_bookmarkslistad"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: first thing ,in your xml you haven't added the orientation for linear layout,second thing is you have added the weightsum to the linear layout then you must set the either height or width of the child view to 0dp along with the required weight for the view(you have already specified it in your xml).  and now my question is what do you want to achieve actually?? Do you want the two buttons at the center of the screen?

Comment: and my suggestion is instead of using fill parent use match parent since both do the same work and also fill parent in deprecated,

Comment: @pankajkhedekar, thank u for ur answer. Actually i want to set textview and spinners with width ratio 3:7 of the screen width and this is in a layout that located on the center of the screen and have another layout in the bottom of the screen with three buttons with width ratio 3:4:3..... (i hope u got it, sorry for my bad english)

Comment: thank u for ur reply... i have done with ur suggestion...."first thing ,in your xml you haven't added the orientation for linear layout,second thing is you have added the weightsum to the linear layout then you must set the either height or width of the child view to 0dp along with the required weight for the view(you have already specified it in your xml)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for late reply. it will help you. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" hello world"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7"></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn1"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn2"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn3"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply... i have done with ur first reply with good suggestion..... and i think in this code orientation will not avail in relative layout

Comment: your welcome :) .yup. orientation is only for linear layout. you can not set orientation property to the relative layout.